# Can you give mishloach manos to yourself?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

My friend teaches at a Sunday school, and made mishloach manos with her class last week.

One very bright student asked her, "What if there's no one for me to give mishloach manos to? I can't give it to my friends in public school (very strict rules about bringing in outside food); can I give it to myself?"

My friend suggested giving it to her sister, but the little girl insisted "Can I give it to myself?" (*my friend took this all as a compliment in her choice of snacks for mishloach manos, but said no, and firmly*)

Between the Manos Halevi and the Terumas HaDeshen, you might get *tzorchei seudah*, but you likely won't get an increase in *ahava* et al (barring [multiple personality disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_identity_disorder)).

But still, I wonder....**do any Jewish sources "explicitly" address the question of giving mishloach manos to yourself?**

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/797/70/).

Comment: Hillel said "if not for myself who will be" or something like that. Although the context was different I am sure that the Rabbi's statement can be applied to allow one to gift themselves mishmash manot.

Comment: @JJLL - Pretty good :-) I may use this as fodder for a follow up question while I still have the opportunity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most sources that deal with this subject make a kal vichomer from mah nishtana where a lone person asks the question themselves and then answers it. Certainly here were there is hanaas goren from the food eaten it works.

Comment: @Shokhet congrats on 10k!

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely, yes. This is permissible.

Esther 9:22 says

מִשְׁלֹחַ מָנוֹת אִישׁ לְרֵעֵהוּ

One should give *mishloach manot* to his "friend"

And, Vayikra 19:18 says

וְאָהַבְתָּ לְרֵעֲךָ כָּמוֹךָ

You should love your friend as yourself

Well, if you love yourself, then, you are your own best friend, so by all means, you can give yourself your own *mishloach manot*. Enjoy yourself, and make sure that you give yourself at least two edibles!